# Преобразование слова PHP из CamelCase в HyphenDelimited

Tags: php

Как средствами `php` получить из `masterRepair` строку `master-repair`?

Comment: слово `master` всегда на первом месте? Или есть какой-то список слов стоящих в начале?

Comment: именно так нужно

Comment: Вы сейчас на мой вопрос ответили? Тогда я боюсь вам тут не помогут

Comment: нужен мне алгоритм который преобразует такие слова
'masterRepair' -> 'master-repair' , 'courierOrder' - > 'courier-order'

Answer (score 2):

### UPD

Самый простой и быстрый вариант заменить при помощи регулярки все вхождения верхнего регистра:

```
$str = 'masterRepairPlusOtherText';
$result = mb_strtolower(preg_replace("/([A-Z])/u", '-$1', $str));
// выведет – string(29) "master-repair-plus-other-text"
var_dump($result);
```

Так же этот код подходит для строк в `UTF-8`.

При этом [mbstring](http://php.net/manual/ru/mbstring.installation.php) должны быть включены или функцию [mb_strtolower()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mb-strtolower.php) заменить на [strtolower()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strtolower.php) если не требуется работа с многобайтовыми строками.

Comment: Засуньте строку ещё в функцию - пусть будет однострочник :)

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример перевода из CamelCase в HyphenDelimited и наоборот:

```
public function seeTestHyphenDelimitedToCamelCase()
{
    $examples = [
            'hyphen-delimited-string',
            'hyphen-Delimited-STRING',
    ];

    foreach ($examples as $example) {
        echo '<p>' . str_replace(' ', '', ucwords(str_replace('-', ' ', $example))) . '</p>';
    }
}

public function seeCamelCaseToHyphenDelimited()
{
    $examples = [
            'CamelCase',
            'nearlyCamelCase',
    ];

    foreach ($examples as $example) {
        echo '<p>' . strtolower(preg_replace('/([a-zA-Z])(?=[A-Z])/', '$1-', $example)) . '</p>';
    }
}
```